# SQL: How can I apply WHERE clause filters for specific aggregate functions in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

With an incomplete data set, I need to perform aggregate functions while avoiding nulls for only the specific aggregate function all from the same table. So for example I tried to put it in subqueries:

```
WITH spend AS (
  SELECT
    (SUM(current_spend)-SUM(baseline_spend))/SUM(baseline_spend) percent_change_spend
  FROM 
   `table_one`
  WHERE
    baseline_spend IS NOT NULL
),

sales AS (
  SELECT
    (SUM(current_sales)-SUM(baseline_sales))/SUM(baseline_sales) percent_change_sales
  FROM
    `table_one`
  WHERE
    baseline_sales IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT
    percentage_change_spend,
    percentage_change_sales
FROM
    table_one ...
```

I can't use a regular query as applying `WHERE baseline_spend IS NOT NULL` or `baseline_sales IS NOT NULL` would affect both aggregate functions as it's filtering the whole data set first.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT:

For example, I would like the spend aggregate to only ignore row 4 when aggregating, and the sales aggregate to only ignore row 2

[image]

I would then want the final result to be:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values so this should do what you want:

```
SELECT (SUM(current_spend)-SUM(baseline_spend)) / SUM(baseline_spend) as percent_change_spend,
       (SUM(current_sales)-SUM(baseline_sales)) / SUM(baseline_sales) as percent_change_sales
FROM `table_one`
```